# How to add project to configuration browser?

Tags: configuration, pharo, monticello, metacello

One easy way of installing projects in [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) is by using a *Configuration Browser*.

How can a developer make his project appear in this browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your configuration appear in the *Configuration Browser*, you have to copy your configuration package into a corresponding repository. For Pharo 3 it is:

http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~Pharo/MetaRepoForPharo30

Comment: And you need to be able to do it. That means you need to ask for been added (usually sending a mail to pharo-dev list). This will change soon, but for now is like that :(

Comment: As a follow-up to Esteban's comment above -- the Meta repos for Pharo 3, 4 and 5 are now public-writeable. (Meaning, you do not need to ask for write access on the mailing list).